# The thickness of the hot air layer above a hot metal

Tags: heat-conduction

I need a simple way to estimate the thickness of the hot air layer above a metal heated up by about 100K above the room temperature. I'm not sure how to go about estimating this.

What happens there, you have heat transport from the metal to the air, but also the hot air about the metal will raise as it is less dense than the rest of the air. There is also thermal radiation to consider.

I think a good definition for the thickness of that hot air is when the temperature of the air immediately above it is very close to the room temperature (maybe 1% of the temperature gradient).

I would definitely appreciate an answer with equations, as they are self more self-explanatory than the text.

Comment: You are talking about the so-called *convection layer (or zone)* in the convection heat transfer model. I doubt very much if there is a simple, analytical method for estimating the thickness of that layer.

Comment: I could try to compute something, but I only have one more day I can work on it, and only hand wavy arguments to support what I'm trying to say.

Comment: There will be a very thin boundary layer around the metal, and as Gert pointed out, a convection layer as well.  The shape and thickness of both layers will depend on the surface roughness of the metal, the temperature difference between the metal and ambient, the orientation of the metal (vertical, horizontal), the shape of the metal (drag coefficients may be involved), ambient air velocity (including that caused by convection currents from the hot metal), etc.  THAT is why engineering heat transfer texts contain empirical equations for each specific situation.

Comment: @DavidWhite Do you know one good text that would be a good starting point?

Comment: @Magicsowon, no - as Gert said, there probably isn't a simple, analyical method for doing the calculation that you want done.